# UIViewRepresentable UITextField skips first character when connected to ObservableObject's @Published property

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit

I have a CustomTextField conforming to UIViewRepresentable. This field is connected to the ViewModel's @Published email property. The ViewModel itself conforms to ObservableObject. When I launch the app on iPhone 12 Pro Max (14.3) simulator, whenever I try to type the first character, it doesn't appear in the field nor it gets added the email's value. The consecutive characters are typed just fine.

Here is the code:

```
import SwiftUI

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var email = ""
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var vm = ViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.blue
            
            CustomTextField(text: $vm.email, placeholder: "Email")
                .frame(height: 40)
                .padding()
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}

struct CustomTextField: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var text: String
    var placeholder: String

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextField {
        let textField = UITextField()
        textField.borderStyle = .roundedRect
        textField.placeholder = placeholder

        textField.autocapitalizationType = .none
        textField.autocorrectionType = .no
        textField.spellCheckingType = .no
        
        textField.delegate = context.coordinator
        return textField
    }

    func updateUIView(_ view: UITextField, context: Context) {
        view.text = text
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(text: $text)
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UITextFieldDelegate {
        @Binding var text: String

        init(text: Binding<String>) {
            _text = text
        }

        func textFieldDidChangeSelection(_ textField: UITextField) {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.text = textField.text ?? ""
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Does anyone know what's wrong here?

Comment: The code you provided works perfectly fine for me. Tested on iOS 14.3 and iPhone 12 Pro Max

Comment: This works fine on mine as well

Comment: @Simon What Xcode version do you have?

Comment: @sheriff_paul Xcode Version 12.4 (12D4e) and Simulator Version 12.4 (940.20)
SimulatorKit 597.13.0.1
CoreSimulator 732.18.6

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in Xcode. Once I upgraded to 12.4, the issue went away.

Answer (score 0):

If you initialize your model in View, you should use `@StateObject` instead of `@ObservedObject`.

Also, you may try assigning `textField.text = text` in the `makeUIView` method.

And I feel like this approach for `Representable` objects is more elegant, take a look ^^

https://github.com/twostraws/VisualEffects